# Doing a left join with Lambda for parent/child results without PK FK

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda

I need to return a result from two tables that have an undefined parent-child relationship:
The parent table has a LinkTypeId and LinkId field that is used to decide which child table is referred to by each row.
So Parent row x could point to Child1, Child2 or even Child3 tables.

Since the results are used together with an entity framework, which only contain an ID field for nullable child objects, I should be able to get a result of parents with nullable children also populated. We map the EF-based results to Classes that reflect our objects as they are to be used.

I got the following query to work, but since it was built in LinqPad the EF is not used, and two recordsets returned. How do I get the Children connected to the Parent?

```
var qry = Parent.GroupJoin(
          ChildItem, 
          dl => dl.LinkId,
          itm => itm.ChildItemId,
          (x,y) => new { Parent = x, ChildItem = y })
    .Where( x => x.Parent.PKId == 123 && x.Parent.LinkTypeId == 1 )
    .SelectMany(
          x => x.ChildItem.DefaultIfEmpty(),
          (x,y) => new { Parent=x.Parent, ChildItem=y}) ;

          qry.Dump();
```

EDIT:
This query returns results, and the correct data at that, but it returns a Generic `List<{Parent, ChildItem}>` **instead of** `IEnumerable<Parent>` with the Parent.Child object populated.

Comment: Why doesn't your query work?

Comment: See my edit above for your answer

Comment: I see. EF will track all queries entities anyway, so you can use `Parent.Child` together with lazy loading and have no further queries to the database going on. `Parent.Child` will be filled from the already loaded objects the first time you access it. Does this answer your question?

Comment: so use `new Parent {...}` instead of `new {...}`

Comment: @usr: EF can not track the Parent.Child relationship as the Parent.child can refer to any of 3 different object types. I updated my question to reflect this. We are mapping from EF to Classes we defined.

Comment: So are you trying to project the EF objects into classes you define (ie a user defined parent / child object) If so it might be a good idea to make this clear in your example, and name the user defined classes differently from the EF classes.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the help of a colleague: Simple really: I should just have joined the ChildItems after the Query statement instead.

```
            var qry= dataContext.Parent
                   .GroupJoin(
                      dataContext.ChildItems,
                      dl => dl.LinkId,
                      itm => (Int32?)(itm.ChildItemId),
                      (x, y) =>
                         new
                         {
                             Parent = x,
                             ChildItems = y
                         }
                   )
                   .Where(x => (((x.Parent.ParentId == 1)) 
                       && (x.Parent.LinkTypeId == 1)
                   )
                   .SelectMany(
                      x => x.ChildItems.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                      (x,y) => new { Parent=x.Parent, ChildItems=y});

            var tmpResult = result.ToList();

            foreach (var line in tmpResult)
            {
                line.Parent.Item = line.ChildItems;
            }

            return tmpResult.Select(a => a.Parent).ToList();
```

Thanks to all who tried helping!